# Efficient re-gridding of large 2-D arrays in python

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation, geospatial

I am trying to find the most efficient way to regrid a portion of a 2-D array to a finer grid. To keep my program general, I would prefer a solution using a standard package like numpy or scipy, but perhaps this is beyond their capacities.

The intended input data is a geotiff DEM (digital elevation models) file, imported with GDAL, and converted to a numpy array. An issue is that many of the input files have no CRS information.

In my MWE below and regridding to a 2x2 grid (for demo) this takes 96s on my local machine. The actual fine grids will be much larger and the fine grid will be created multiple times in a loop. I admit this MWE might be the least efficient way to do this!

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate as interp
import time

nx,ny = 1600,2400 # size of input data
z_in = np.random.normal(size=(nx,ny)) # make input data
x_in,y_in = np.mgrid[0:nx,0:ny]*0.0932248 # make x,y coordinate arrays for input data

# make new (finer) x,y coordinate arrays. none of these x,y coordinates 
# necessarily overlap directly with those of the input dataset.
nx_new,ny_new = 2,2 # size of fine array (in reality, this will be much larger (up to 1000x1000))
x_new,y_new = np.mgrid[0:nx_new,0:ny_new] 
x_new = x_new*0.01 + 60
y_new = y_new*0.01 + 85

# regrid the data
starttime=time.time()
flattened_xy_in = np.array([x_in.flatten(),y_in.flatten()]).transpose()
fine_DEM_z = interp.griddata(flattened_xy_in, z_in.flatten(), (x_new, y_new), method='cubic')
print('that took '+str(time.time()-starttime)+' seconds...')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input is data that lies on a regular rectangular grid, therefore you're wasting resources by using `griddata` which can be used to interpolate *unstructured* data. Instead it would make sense to use `RectBivariateSpline` which can speed up the interpolation massively if you already have data on a grid.

Comment: Good tip and it might be the solution for me with a bit more pre-processing. This issue is that some of the input datasets, although structured, are slightly rotated or non-orthogonal. RectBivariateSpline takes 1-d vectors for x and y.